# How to determine which version of Oracle Commerce (ATG) is running?

Tags: atg, oracle-commerce

I am trying to determine the precise version of ATG which is running e.g. 10.2.x.  I know that dyn/admin has the following:
[image: ATG dyn/admin running products]

The product version is obvious but how do I know the precise version that is running? i.e. 10.2 or 10.2.1 or 10.2.2 or 10.2.3

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact version is normally held in the `MANIFEST.MF` files. Just locate the `ATG-Patch-Version`, `ATG-Version`, and `ATG-Version-Full` for these files and it will tell you.

Here it is from my ATG9.1p4 install:

```
ATG-Patch-Version: 9.1p4
ATG-Version: 9.1
ATG-Version-Full: 9.1
```

and here it is for my ATG11.0 install:

```
ATG-Version: 11.0
ATG-Version-Full: 11.0
```

Comment: Thanks! It used to be a lot easier when running DAS as it would print on the console during start up.  This seems to have been removed now that it runs WebLogic/WAS/JBoss.

Comment: For reference I ran the following commands on the *nix terminal in the <ATG_INSTALL> folder to print out a full list of all the application versions and patches: `find . -name MANIFEST.MF -exec grep -i "ATG-Version-Full:" /dev/null {} \;` and `find . -name MANIFEST.MF -exec grep -i "ATG-Patch-Version:" /dev/null {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

Product version should show the exact version with installed patch and fixpack:
http://c2n.me/iIXGkn.png

So as you see it shows that I am on 9.3 fixpack 1.

Also, you can find the information about current patch/fixpack and their history in ATG/patch folder. It contains:

1. current_fixpack.txt - information about the installed fixpack
2. fixpack_history.txt - information about all installed/uninstalled fixpacks
3. current_patch.txt - information about the installed patch
4. patch_history.txt - information about all installed/uninstalled patches

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  This does still not give me the exact version.  The only file which is present is `patch_history.txt` and the contents of this file is: `ATG10.2 BUILT on Mon 04 1 08:01:57 EDT 2013`.  It is still not clear which version of 10.2.x this is.

Comment: It means that you have ATG 10.2 without any patches.